# Is there a way to fetch a URL that ends with a dot-segment?

Tags: javascript, url, fetch, rfc3986

My goal is to fetch a URL that ends with a dot-segment, so a URL that ends with a literal dot/period: `.`

**Example:**

I expected the following invocation of fetch to result in an `HTTP GET` request on the base URI of the site with the path `/api/users/.` (notice the literal dot at the end)

```js
await fetch("/api/users/.")
```

Instead, it results in the path `<base URI>/api/users/` to be requested (notice the *missing* dot)

This section of RFC 3986 describes the behaviour to remove dot-segments: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-5.2.4

Now, I tried to URI-escape the dot with `%2e`, giving me the following request path: `/api/users/%2e`

Unfortunately, the same behaviour occurs, tested on Firefox and on Chrome.

I am baffled how to achieve this in a Browser-based environment using the Browser's `fetch` API.

I know that using cURL this is as easy as specifying an additional parameter (otherwise the same behaviour occurs also using `cURL`):

```bash
curl --path-as-is "http://localhost:8080/api/users/."
```

However, I have not found any such config possibility for `fetch`.

Comment: that link does not have anything to do with removing the trailing `.`

Answer (score 0):

The workaround to encode the dot-segment with `%2e` does solve the problem.

Source of confusion was: A server may decide to redirect `<url>/.` to `<url>`, so maybe check the network panel for a `302 Found` where a different link is provided as header.

I didn't notice this behaviour at first and together with a few other issues I was confused and thought the workaround didn't work.